# MS project server Error while updating team through SoapUI

Tags: xml, web-services, asmx, soapui, ms-project-server-2013

I want to update project team of project using Soap UI, But i m getting GeneralUnhandledException while doing the operation through Soap UI. Following is my request body and response :

URL of asmx service : http://vmw2k8sp136167:30/_vti_bin/PSI/Project.asmx

Request :

```html
<proj:QueueUpdateProjectTeam>
   <proj:JobUid>e0b1816d-daf7-e411-97e7-005056ad0852</proj:JobUid>
   <proj:sessionUid>e0b1816d-daf7-e411-97e7-005056ad0753</proj:sessionUid>
   <proj:projectUid>e0b1816d-daf7-e411-97e7-005056ad0472</proj:projectUid>
   <proj:dataset>
       <ProjectTeamDataSet>
           <ProjectTeam>
               <PROJ_UID>e0b1816d-daf7-e411-97e7-005056ad0472</PROJ_UID>
               <RES_UID>04aba817-74d8-e411-8329-005056ad0472</RES_UID>
               <RES_NAME>kapil</RES_NAME>
               <RES_BOOKING_TYPE>0</RES_BOOKING_TYPE>
               <RES_TYPE>2</RES_TYPE>
               <RES_IS_ENTERPRISE_RESOURCE>true</RES_IS_ENTERPRISE_RESOURCE>
           </ProjectTeam>
           <ProjectTeam>
               <PROJ_UID>e0b1816d-daf7-e411-97e7-005056ad0472</PROJ_UID>
               <RES_UID>db9283f1-c1e9-e411-a291-005056ad0472</RES_UID>
               <RES_NAME>ajinkya</RES_NAME>
               <RES_BOOKING_TYPE>0</RES_BOOKING_TYPE>
               <RES_TYPE>2</RES_TYPE>
               <RES_IS_ENTERPRISE_RESOURCE>true</RES_IS_ENTERPRISE_RESOURCE>
           </ProjectTeam>
       </ProjectTeamDataSet>
   </proj:dataset>
</proj:QueueUpdateProjectTeam>
```

Responce :

```html
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode>s:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">ProjectServerError(s) LastError=GeneralUnhandledException Instructions: Pass this into PSClientError constructor to access all error information</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <errinfo>
               <general>
                  <class name="General Unhandled Exception in _Project.QueueUpdateProjectTeam_">
                     <error id="42" name="GeneralUnhandledException" uid="08d24c08-e2f7-e411-97e7-005056ad0472" Exception="System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.DataAccessLayer.ProjectDal.GetSessionInfo(Guid projectUid, Guid&amp; sessionID, String&amp; sessionDescription)
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.Project.ValidateSession(Guid projectUid, Guid sessionUid)
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.Project.QueueUpdateProjectTeam(Guid JobUid, Guid sessionUid, Guid projectUid, ProjectTeamDataSet dataset)
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Wcf.Implementation.ProjectImpl.&lt;>c__DisplayClass7f.&lt;QueueUpdateProjectTeam>b__7e()
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Wcf.Implementation.WcfMethodInvocation.InvokeBusinessObjectMethod(String businessObjectName, String methodName, IEnumerable`1 actions)"/>
                  </class>
               </general>
            </errinfo>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: This is a server-side error. This is not something you can fix on the client side. You will have to contact the developer.

Comment: @SiKing this is web service call which is exposed by MS project server, so there is no developer kind of thing here. Also i didn't changed anything on project server side. It will be helpful if you tell me what exactly developer have to do for making successful call to this API means any configuration changes or anything else.